# Argument Count Mismatch (Not Event Related)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, arguments, flash-cs6

I'm getting this error but my function is supposed to accept 6 parameters?!? 
Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

```
Starting Test
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on edu.clips2.movieclip::ubContainerSimple$/create(). Expected 1, got 6.
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at edu.clips2.ui::ubButtonSimple$/create()[/Volumes/Work/CLIPS Repo/classes/as3/edu/clips2/ui/ubButtonSimple.as:79]
    at edu.ewins.wrapper::ActivityHelpingHandButton()[/Volumes/Work/CLIPS Repo/classes/as3/edu/ewins/wrapper/ActivityHelpingHandButton.as:34]
    at edu.ewins.wrapper::ActivityHelpingHandButton$/create()[/Volumes/Work/CLIPS Repo/classes/as3/edu/ewins/wrapper/ActivityHelpingHandButton.as:52]
    at test::AS3Test/init()[/Volumes/Work/CLIPS Repo/classes/as3/test/AS3Test.as:67]
    at test::AS3Test()[/Volumes/Work/CLIPS Repo/classes/as3/test/AS3Test.as:63]
```

Here is the function signature

```
package edu.clips2.movieclip {
    ...
    public class ubContainerSimple {
        ...
        public static function create(parent:DisplayObjectContainer, instanceName:String= null, depth:Number=-1, mcProps:Object=null, linkageName:String= null):MovieClip {
            ...
        }
```

For simplification here is approximately what was happening...

ubButtonSimple took this array:

```
var a:Array = [ubContainerSimple, [target, "foregroundContainer", 6, {x:0, y:0}, {alpha:1, rotation:0, scaleX:0.4, scaleY:0.4, x:6, y:11}, "HelpingHand"]];
```

and then called

```
a[0].create.apply(null, a[1]);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using when you are calling that function?
(and i count 5 parameters)

Comment: Of course it was something stupidly simple! I was missing a parameter and when I added the missing parameter it works. No idea why it said expected 1 instead of 5 though. That really threw me off.

Comment: Now my function is `public static function create(parent:DisplayObjectContainer, instanceName:String=null, depth:Number=-1, mcProps:Object=null, linkageProps:Object=null, linkageName:String=null):MovieClip {` and it works!

Comment: @JohanLindkvist if you want to post that as a solution I can mark it as correct and give you credit. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Then i will do than :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only count 5 parameters in your create function

Comment: Don't know why the debugger said it expected 1 parameter instead of 5 but adding in the 6th solved the problem. Thanks!